# Is it possible to compile chromium and nwjs for PowerPC?

Tags: node.js, chromium, powerpc, nwjs

Is it possible to compile `nwjs` for `powerpc` using `IBM PowerPC ported versions of node.js`: https://github.com/andrewlow/node and V8: https://github.com/andrewlow/v8ppc?

Answer (score 0):

after doing research, In order to compile nwjs for power PC, the whole chromium should be compiled for powerpc and it will require a good team in c++ to work for couple weeks to do so